# Calculate the number of weekday and weekend hours between 2 timestamp params in javascript

Tags: javascript, date, datetime

I want to calculate the number of weekday-hours and weekend-hours within a given 2 timestamp range. It is sure the timestamp ranges are in hours, it doesn't contain minutes or seconds values in it.

attempt:

```
function getWeekdayWeekendHours(fromTimestamp, tillTimestamp) {
  let weekdayhours = 0;
  let weekendhours = 0;
  // fix the GMT issue by decreasing timestamp by 5:30
  const fromTime = fromTimestamp - 19800;
  const tillTime = tillTimestamp - 19800;

  let currentDate = new Date(fromTime * 1000);
  const tillDate = new Date(tillTime * 1000);
  while (currentDate < tillDate) {
    if (currentDate.getDay() !== 0 && currentDate.getDay() !== 6) 
    weekdayhours += 1;
    else weekendhours += 1;
    currentDate = currentDate.addHours(1);
  }
  return { weekdayhours, weekendhours };
}

// eslint-disable-next-line no-extend-native
Date.prototype.addHours = function (h) {
  this.setHours(this.getHours() + h);
  return this;
};
```

Comment: @ecg8 was able to solve the problem after trying, is there a way to optimize instead of a loop?

Comment: I'm not sure you'll get your desired outcome all the time with this. What will happen for users who are not in your timezone? Also, this will probably not work accurately this weekend in countries with daylight savings. Have you looked at momentjs?

Comment: Where is the question here? You've made a statement about what you want, then posted some code with nothing about the issues you're having or errors you're getting.

Comment: You don't need to iterate over every hour between the 2 timestamps. Check my answer. I use moment but you could achieve the same thing with native Date.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a function that should work, provided you don't mind using lodash & moment.

```
const moment = require("moment")
const lodash = require("lodash")

function getHours(ts1, ts2) {
    const weekends = [6, 7] // the isoWeekday of saturday & sunday
    const [m1, m2] = [moment(ts1), moment(ts2)].sort()  // makes sure earlier ts is first
    const numDays = Math.ceil(m2.diff(m1, "days", true)) + 1

    let weekdayHrs = 0
    let weekendHrs = 0
    lodash.range(numDays).forEach(idx => {
        let diffHours = 0
        let start
        let end

        // figure out start, end timestamps
        switch (idx) {
            case 0:
                start = m1
                end = m1.clone().add(1, "days").hours(0).minutes(0).seconds(0).milliseconds(0)
                break
            case numDays - 1:
                end = m2
                start = m2.clone().hours(0).minutes(0).seconds(0).milliseconds(0)
                break
            default:
                start = m1.clone().hours(0).minutes(0).seconds(0).milliseconds(0).add(idx, "days")
                end = start.clone().add(1, "days")
                end = end.isBefore(m2) ? end : m2
                break
        }

        diffHours = end.diff(start, "hours")
        const dayOfWeek = start.isoWeekday()
        const isWeekend = weekends.includes(dayOfWeek)
        if (isWeekend) {
            weekendHrs += diffHours
        } else {
            weekdayHrs += diffHours
        }

        // you can remove these 2 lines from the function. This just prints the total per day.
        const names = ["mon", "tue", "wed", "thu", "fri", "sat", "sun"] 
        console.log(idx, names[dayOfWeek - 1], start.format("MMM/DD hh:mm A"), "to", end.format("MMM/DD hh:mm A"), "=", diffHours,  isWeekend ? "weekend hrs": "hrs")
    })

    return { weekdayHrs, weekendHrs, total: weekdayHrs + weekendHrs }
}
```

Here is some example output:

```
const ts1 = new Date(2019, 9, 18) // Oct 18 2019 12:00 AM
const ts2 = new Date(2019, 9, 25) // Oct 25 2019 12:00 AM
console.log(getHours(ts1, ts2))

// output:= { weekdayHrs: 120, weekendHrs: 48, total: 168 }


const ts3 = new Date(2019, 9, 18, 10) // Oct 18 2019 10:00 AM
const ts4 = new Date(2019, 9, 22, 13) // Oct 22 2019 1:00 PM
console.log(getHours(ts3, ts4))

// output:= { weekdayHrs: 64, weekendHrs: 48, total: 112 }
```

Comment: An answer shouldn't require a library not mentioned or tagged in the OP. Including two such libraries is somewhat over–achieving at the wrong thing. ;-)  It should also explain why the OP is having their issues and how your code fixes it. The OP hasn't noted any issues, so rather hard to answer.

Comment: It's pretty trivial to replace what I'm using lodash for but momentjs isn't. ecg8 mentioned the library as well. Both of these libraries are pretty standard in the javascript world.

But to answer you question, the biggest difference between what he is doing & what I am is the fact that he is iterating over every hour between the 2 timestamps; I am only iterating over the days between the timestamps and doing some math to figure out how many hours go into each day, and consequently how many hours go into weekends / weekdays.